# WordPress Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, wordpress

> ( ! ) Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '' /mvc_controller.php on line 265

I get this above error despite trying so many suggestions in the forums, stackexchange etc.

I am developing a plugin in WordPress 4.0.1 using WP MVC, and it also encapsulates ORM concept that is in-built with WP MVC. I couldnt find a solution for this.

Below is the code: 
**(Public Controller)**

/app/controllers/geozone_rules_controller.php

```
    <?php

class GeozoneRulesController extends MvcPublicController {

    var $after = array('set_geozonerules');

        public function set_geozonerules() {
            $this->load_model('GeozoneRule');           
            $geozonerules = $this->GeozoneRule->find();
            $this->set('geozonerules', $geozonerules);
        }

        // Overwrite the default index() method to include the 'is_public' => true condition
        public function index() {

        $objects = $this->GeozoneRule->find(array(
                                    'joins'     =>  array('Geozone', 'Country', 'Zone'),
                                    'includes'  =>  array('Geozone', 'Country', 'Zone'),
                                    'selects'   =>  array('Geozone.id, Geozone.geozone_name',
                                                    array('Country.id, Country.country_name',
                                                    array('Zone.id', 'Zone.zone_name',
                                                    array('GeozoneRule.id', 'GeozoneRule.ordering')
                                                    )
                                            )))
                                    );
        $this->set('objects', $objects);

        // pagination
        $this->params['page'] = empty($this->params['page']) ? 1 : $this->params['page'];
        $this->params['conditions'] = array('is_public' => true);
        $collection = $this->model->paginate($this->params);
        $this->set('objects', $collection['objects']);
        $this->set_pagination($collection);

        echo '<a href="admin.php?page=mvc_geozone_rules-add">Add New Geozone Rule</a>';

    }

    // GeozoneRule selects only GeozoneRule names and ids by default; to select all fields from GeozoneRule,
    // we'll overwrite the default show() method
    public function show() {

        $object = $this->model->find_by_id($this->params['id'], array(
            'includes' => array(
                            'Geozone',
                            'Country',
                            'Zone',
                            'GeozoneRule' => array(
                                                'selects' => 'GeozoneRule.*'
                                                )
                            )
                            ));

        if (!empty($object)) {
            $this->set('object', $object);
            $this->render_view('show', array('layout' => 'public'));
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**Model:**

```
    <?php

class GeozoneRule extends MvcModel {

    var $table = '{prefix}w2store_geozonerules';
    var $primary_key = 'id';
    var $display_field = 'id';
    var $default_order = 'sort_name';
    var $includes = array('Geozone', 'Country', 'Zone');

    var $has_and_belongs_to_many = array(
                        'GeozoneRule' => array(
                                        'join_table' => array('{prefix}w2store_geozones',
                                                            'fields' => array('id', 'geozone_name')),
                                                        array('{prefix}w2store_countries',
                                                            'fields' => array('id', 'country_name')),
                                                        array('{prefix}w2store_zones',
                                                            'fields' => array('id', 'zone_name')),
                                                            'fields' => array('id', 'ordering')
                                                            )
                                        );

    public function after_find($object) {
        if (isset($object->geozonerules)) {
            $geozonerule_names = array();
            foreach($object->geozonerules as $geozonerule) {
                $geozonerule_names[] = $geozonerule->name;
            }
        }

    //  print_r ($object);
    //  exit;
    }

    public function after_save($object) {
        $this->update_sort_name($object);
    }

    public function update_sort_name($object) {

        $sort_name = $object->geozonerule_name;
        $this->update($object->__id, array('sort_name' => $sort_name));
    }


}

?>
```

and now the error i got:

> ```
> Warning: require(): Filename cannot be empty in /mvc_controller.php
> ```
>
> on line 265 Call Stack
>     Time    Memory  Function    Location . . 11 0.0659  3870616

Any possible solutions will be of much help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You showed all your code except the important piece: `mvc_controller.php on line 265`

Comment: line# 265 mvc_controller.php:  require $filepath;

Comment: and what's $filepath ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. Simple error made a lot of fuss.

In views/admin/  folder, there is a folder for the model GeozoneRule in the name 'geozonerules' and it was renamed to 'geozone_rules'. Now it is ok.

Naming of folders and files needs careful attention.

Thanks folks.